# Incorrect application erb file when switching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3.2.

In my app I have an `application.html.erb` which serves 'normal' mode and an `application.mobile.erb` file which serves 'mobile' mode.

When I load up the home page in 'normal' mode the `application.html.erb` file correctly is served up with the 'normal' mode home page `home.html.erb`. When I switch to 'mobile' mode the `application.mobile.erb` is correctly served up with the 'mobile' mode home page `home.mobile.erb`. When I switch back to 'normal' mode  the correct 'normal' mode `home.html.erb` file is served up but with the incorrect `application.mobile.erb` (of the 'mobile' mode) file.

If I refresh the page after the `application.mobile.erb` is incorrectly served up the `application.html.erb` is correctly loaded up.

This is the link used to switch from normal mode to mobile mode

```
<a href="/en?mobile=0" class="ui-link">Full Site</a>
```

This is the link used to switch from mobile mode to normal mode

```
<a href="/en?mobile=1" class="ui-link">Mobile Site</a>
```

If I change the normal switch so it is requesting from a different subdomain like this (This is a subdomain I have already set up)

```
<a href="http://mobile.localhost.local:3000/en?mobile=0" class="ui-link">Full Site</a>
```

the application erb file is switched correctly and everything behaves. Note: it doesn't work if I add the same host.

Presumably rails routing handles paths on the same server differently but I don't really understand how and if this is a bug?

Any one know what is going on?

**UPDATE**

The code in the application_controller which processes the argument is:

```
before_filter :set_locale, :prepare_for_mobile
...
def mobile_device?
  if session[:mobile_param]
     session[:mobile_param] == "1"
  else
     request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
  end
end
helper_method :mobile_device?

def prepare_for_mobile
  session[:mobile_param] = params[:mobile] if params[:mobile]
  request.format = :mobile if mobile_device?
end
```

And I have this in my mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile
```

Here is an example of where it is happening http://www.zode64.com

Note the mobile and normal links in the top right have new subdomains, if you use firebug to change to the current subdomain it will still open the correct page but with the wrong `application.erb`

Comment: Please add your code where you have logics with params[:mobile] variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in this logic:

```
before_filter :set_locale, :prepare_for_mobile
...

def prepare_for_mobile
  session[:mobile_param] = params[:mobile] if params[:mobile]
  request.format = :mobile if mobile_device?
end
```

If params[:mobile] changes from 1 to 0 (that is, from mobile to full-site), both session variable and request.format are not set and the site continues to behave as if it is still in mobile mode.